# Why is the proximity sensor suddenly shining brightly?

Tags: proximity-sensor

Top right is where the "light / proximity sensor" lives, according to the manual. It is clearly visible as white light on this photo - that is expected. What is NOT expected is that it is also clearly visible to the naked eye?! It's a tiny red dot, impossible to photograph as such.

That sensor has never been visible before! **Why is it visible now?**

[image: x]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't find it unusual that this sensor is active. Are you sure the red dot was not visible before? May be it was just so dark that you did not notice it?

Comment: The sensor is probably always active. But it has *never* been visible, and indeed is not visible on any of my other phones. This is visible in normal indoor lighting. The sensor uses infrared which is not visible to the human eye and I am sure I did not suddenly develop weird super powers.

Comment: It is **light**/proximity sensor as per details highlighted.light sensor is supposed to measure ambient light. I don't know why it is so clearly visible but a couple of things to try - go into sunlight or bright light stay there for a while and come back indoors to check, check if selfie camera is on, toggle auto brightness

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun From what I found, that might be the front facing selfie flash. Double check your tile settings or perhaps a third party app is turning it on/left on.

Comment: Does the proximity and light sensor still work? Use a sensor app to test. May be the receiver part of the sensor does not work anymore and therefore causes the ir led to be constantly active.

Comment: @MorrisonChang it's not the front flash, see the feature chart (third image).

Comment: You can check if the light sensor is working fine, using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.andr7e.sensortest). More on Play Store, I just picked up well rated